# wrong mime type error

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

i am new to laravel.Here i am trying to create an image upload and validation functionality .I am using laravel 5.2.I have the following form in my create.blade.php file.

```
   {!!Form::open(array('url'=>'user')) !!}

   {!!Form::label('name','Your name')!!}
   {!!Form::text('name')!!}
   </br>
   {!!Form::label('image','Upload an image')!!}
   {!! Form::file('image') !!}
    </br>                      
    {!!Form::label('password','Type Password')!!}</br>
    {!!Form::password('password','',array('placeholder'=>'put your password here'))!!}
    </br>


    {!!Form::submit('submit')!!}
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

in my userController.php resource controller ,inside store() function i have the following validation rule defined :

```
$rules = array(
   'name' => 'unique:users,name|required|alpha_num',
   'password'=>'required',
   'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|required|max:10000'
);
```

no matter what image i upload i am getting the following error.How i can solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: can you try image/jpeg instead of jpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because the image is not being uploaded. You need to set the `files => true` whenever you are opening the form. For example see the following code

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'user','method'=>'POST', 'files'=>true)) !!}

{!! Form::close()!!}
```

Comment: If you think this answered your question , please mark this as the correct answer to help the next person stuck at the same issue - thanks

Comment: thanks.. now i am having the following error :  Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available

Comment: This is because the fileinfo.dll is not available. Uncomment the following line in php.ini in the php folder by removing the semi-colon in the front of that line
extension=php_fileinfo.dll You will have to restart the webserver and rerun php artisan again.

Comment: Glad i could of any help .. :)